# how do you load more than a library in FreePascal?

Tags: windows, dll, freepascal

I can load perfectly the first DLL, but if I try to load a second DLL it fails.

INFO:

- OS: Windows Vista
- FPC: 2.4.4
- No matter if I load the second DLL from an EXE or from inside the first DLL, the second fails.
- No matter if the first DLL is loaded statically, the second just fails.
- No matter which is the second DLL to be loaded.
- I control the source code of the DLLs.
- There are no external dependencies.
- It happen with very simple DLLs.
- GetLastError() returns the 487 error (ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS).
- It only happens with DLLs generated with FPC.

There is something I'm missing and I can't figure it out.

Thanks

ANSWER: ok I found my problem, I had the -WN command line switch in my fp.cfg file

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're calling a wrapper for Win32 LoadLibrary().

You should be able to invoke multiple different .dll's without problem.

SUGGESTION:
Check GetLastError and see what the error code was

ALSO:

- Maybe it's something about that particular .dll, or the way you're using it.
- Run the "[depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)" tool on your .exe, your .dll's, and any .dll you load dynamically.
  Make sure all dependencies are resolved.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I updated the question with more info